# Adding leading zeros to a Javascript timer

Tags: javascript, timer, countdown

I'm attempted to add leading zeros to the seconds value and I keep running into errors. I've tried a number of selected solutions posted here and can't seem to make it work.

I'm pulling values from the spans because those values are coming from the database.

```
var timer = $('.timer');

$('.prev-button,.next-button').hide();

setInterval(function () {

    var m = $('.min', timer),
        s = $('.sec', timer);

    if (m.length == 0 && parseInt(s.html()) <= 0) {
        timer.html('Proceed to the Next Slide');
        $('.prev-button,.next-button').fadeIn();
    }

    if (parseInt(s.html()) <= 0) {
        m.html(parseInt(m.html() - 1));
        s.html(60);
    }

    if (parseInt(s.html()) < 10) {

        $('.sec').prepend(0)

    }


    if (parseInt(m.html()) <= 0) {

        timer.html('Time remaining for this slide - <span class="sec">59</span> seconds')

    }

    s.html(parseInt(s.html() -1));

}, 1000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/certainstrings/a2uJ2/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've modified your Fiddle to make it work. http://jsfiddle.net/a2uJ2/3/

You should store the time in javascript int vars instead of reading it from the html elements every time. This causes maintainability problem as you are attaching logic to the layout of your html document.

I haven't fixed all your code but i've created two variables that are used to perform the calculations instead.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things: You'd be better off registering a start time, and comparing against that inside the interval function. Timers are not guaranteed to be precise, but will instead trigger on *or after* the interval you specify. If the computer's busy, the timer might be late.

Also, if you're using `parseInt`, always, *always* specify a radix argument (the number base). If you don't, the string "08" will will be parsed to "0" because a leading zero is intepreted as an octal (base-8). So use `parseInt(string, 10)` to parse to a normal base-10 number.

As for adding the leading zero, I'd say you should keep a couple variable for total amount of seconds, rather than reading/writing to the elements all the time.

[Updated you jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a2uJ2/6/)

```
var duration, startTime, interval;

duration = parseInt($(".min").text(), 10) * 60 + parseInt($(".sec").text(), 10);
startTime = (new Date()).getTime();

function countDown() {
    var elapsed, remaining, m, s;
    elapsed = ((new Date()).getTime() - startTime) / 1000;
    remaining = duration - elapsed;

    if(remaining <= 0) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        $(".timer").text('Proceed to the Next Slide');
        $('.prev-button,.next-button').fadeIn();
    } else {
        m = String(Math.round(remaining / 60));
        s = String(Math.round(remaining % 60));
        if( s < 10 ) {
            s = "0" + s;
        }
        $(".min").text(m);
        $(".sec").text(s);
    }
}

interval = setInterval(countDown, 500);
```

This is just a minimal change from you code. I'd probably do something fundamentally different to keep the markup and JS as separate as possible, and so on and so forth, but this works too.

Answer (score 0):

try it like this:

```
if (parseInt(s.html()) < 10) {

        $('.sec').val('0' + $('.sec').val());

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to treat the value as a `string` rather than as an `int`. JavaScript is pretty aggressive about converting things that look like numbers into numbers, and that's what's happening here.

Comment: That's what I was slowly coming to realize as I was using typeof() to determine what was getting parsed. Thanks